# sh: 1: react-native: not found npm ERR! code 127

Tags: linux, react-native, ubuntu, installation

I installed React Native according to the installation instructions. I get an error (npx react-native init MyProject) when creating a new project.

```
sh: 1: react-native: not found
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /home/hgtuser
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c react-native init MyProject
```

- Node Version: v15.4.0
- Npm Version : 7.0.15
- Java Version: openjdk 11.0.9.1 2020-11-04
- Watchman Version: 20201205.222256.0

Why am I getting this error on Ubuntu? What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I recently fixed this issue, by using the command `sudo npm install` on ubuntu 20